# Prevent Caching Views in ASP.NET Core in VS 19

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, visual-studio-2019

I am new to ASP.NET core and I am trying to build a small web app but whenver I make a change to a view in debugging mode, I have to restart the application to see the new changes.

I tried few tricks but they did not work and even decorating a specific view with the filter

```
  [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

[image]

Comment: You might need to enable [runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.

**Second**, Update the project's Startup.ConfigureServices method to include a call to AddRazorRuntimeCompilation.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

Then you can update the page without restart the project.

[image]